# How to handle ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some task depending to healthcheck endpoint.
I need to get some response from backend or get `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` this error if we outside some network.

Currently i trying to send request to my endpoint and locally i get error with status: 0 but on the live server i've got TypeError. Any ideas how i can handle `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`?

p.s. no matter what request im using, `fetch` and `xmlhttprequest` doesnt work to

UPD:
On the live server i can get CORS error from back-end but its ok for me, and im sure that i have access to other endpoints. Locally and outside the network ill get `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: If you find a solution to your problem, I would be very grateful if you could share it.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cookies:
Browser cookies can block your Internet DNS and then cause the `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. You can try clearing browser cookies to fix this error.

Or

Flush and renew DNS
Flushing and renewing DNS is a very good way to fix the `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error — this method is quite easy to perform and it is very effective.